# Create table from a select statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a table based on a query. The query works as a SELECT statement, but when I add CREATE TABLE before, it throws an error. Any feedback as to why this might be happening?

I'm using DBeaver with a Microsoft SQL Server database.

```
CREATE TABLE CovidDeaths AS
SELECT iso_code, continent, location, date, population, total_cases, new_cases, new_cases_smoothed, total_deaths, new_deaths, new_deaths_smoothed, total_cases_per_million, new_cases_per_million, new_cases_smoothed_per_million, total_deaths_per_million, new_deaths_per_million, new_deaths_smoothed_per_million, reproduction_rate, icu_patients, icu_patients_per_million, hosp_patients, hosp_patients_per_million, weekly_icu_admissions, weekly_icu_admissions_per_million, weekly_hosp_admissions, weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million
FROM owid_covid_data ocd
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16   Please see here valid example how it should be done

Comment: You're doing oracle syntax. for mssql, you do "select iso_code, continent,... etc into CovidDeaths from owid_covid_data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to create a table with data, you can't create a table and do a select.. because not exist the data yet.

I think is it what are you tryng to do

```
SELECT 
    iso_code,
    continent,
    location,
    date,
    population,
    total_cases,
    new_cases,
    new_cases_smoothed,
    total_deaths,
    new_deaths,
    new_deaths_smoothed,
    total_cases_per_million,
    new_cases_per_million,
    new_cases_smoothed_per_million,
    total_deaths_per_million,
    new_deaths_per_million,
    new_deaths_smoothed_per_million,
    reproduction_rate,
    icu_patients,
    icu_patients_per_million,
    hosp_patients,
    hosp_patients_per_million,
    weekly_icu_admissions,
    weekly_icu_admissions_per_million,
    weekly_hosp_admissions,
    weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million
INTO
    CovidDeaths 
FROM
    owid_covid_data ocd
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct syntax for SQL server, you could try something like this

```
SELECT iso_code, continent, location, date, population, total_cases, new_cases, new_cases_smoothed, total_deaths, new_deaths, new_deaths_smoothed, total_cases_per_million, new_cases_per_million, new_cases_smoothed_per_million, total_deaths_per_million, new_deaths_per_million, new_deaths_smoothed_per_million, reproduction_rate, icu_patients, icu_patients_per_million, hosp_patients, hosp_patients_per_million, weekly_icu_admissions, weekly_icu_admissions_per_million, weekly_hosp_admissions, weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million
INTO CovidDeaths 
FROM owid_covid_data ocd
```

hope was i help you

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked

```
SELECT iso_code, continent, location, date, population, total_cases, new_cases, new_cases_smoothed, total_deaths, new_deaths, new_deaths_smoothed, total_cases_per_million, new_cases_per_million, new_cases_smoothed_per_million, total_deaths_per_million, new_deaths_per_million, new_deaths_smoothed_per_million, reproduction_rate, icu_patients, icu_patients_per_million, hosp_patients, hosp_patients_per_million, weekly_icu_admissions, weekly_icu_admissions_per_million, weekly_hosp_admissions, weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million
    into CovidDeaths
FROM owid_covid_data ocd
```